# how to Calculate the probability of word and predict next word using NLTK Python N grams

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

Im trying to implment tri grams and to predict the next possible word with the highest probability and calculate some word probability, given a long text or corpus.

Following is my code so far for which i am able to get the sets of input data.

```
words = "If I had stayed in at budget chain hotels ; not pricier historic hotels ; such as Millenium Park ; the Aon center ( there is a Starbucks at the bottom ; but only limited opening hours ; the lobby ; but when the young woman at the front desk ; someone finally came and said that it was y husband 's first trip to Chicago and the hotel is first class and the accommodations are unbeatable ."
tri = trigrams(words.split(" "))
```

Comment: You have to build a [language model](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.model.html).

Comment: can you provide any example ?

Comment: Have a look at the [source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html#NgramModel): there's an example in the constructor docstring.

Comment: i am tried i think document here is outdated, the actual library has other fields https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/model/nltk/model/ngram.py and i dont find anything to build n gram using that classes

Comment: Can you update your post to include the code you have tried which doesn't work? Please also specify the NLTK version you are using (in my experience, NLTK even introduced backwards-incompatible changes in minor-version updates).

Comment: You can use the `generate` function of [`nltk.ConditionalProbDist`](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.LaplaceProbDist.html). This selects a random word using the probability distribution. The `max` function will choose the word with highest probability.